# How to test that an angular factory function using a promise is throwing an error in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise

Here's how my function looks like.

```
var myFunc = function(){
   return functionReturningaPromise()
          .then(function(){
              //success, doesn't matter what happens here
          })
          .catch(function(err){
              //handle error here and then throw to handle higher
              throw new Error('Error in my function');
          })
}
```

I need the function to be this way to handle an error inside this function and then throw an error to handle on higher level. But i don't know how to test it with jasmine. I know how to control the promises for testing and my basic set up looks like this:

```
it('Should throw an error', inject(function(alert) {
    var instance = instanceFactory.createInstance(someData);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(someFactory, 'someMethod').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    //instance contains the throwing function above 

    instance.myFunc(otherData);

    deferred.reject({data: '12 - error'});
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(instance.myFunc).toThrow();

}));
```

Obviously, the error is not found by jasmine. So how to test the error throw in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$q` does not work well with native `throw`, you should use `$q` API to re-throw or create new errors inside promise chain. Some Q/A to read about it:

- [Promise.catch() does not catch exception in AngularJS unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538364/promise-catch-does-not-catch-exception-in-angularjs-unit-test)
- [Why can I not throw inside a Promise.catch handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715367/why-can-i-not-throw-inside-a-promise-catch-handler)
- [AngularJS - Promises rethrow caught exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324942/angularjs-promises-rethrow-caught-exceptions)

The solution will be to use `return $q.reject('Error in my function')` instead of `throw new Error('Error in my function');`.

But the open question is how to test it. Basically you can make use of promise chains and add one more `.catch()` in test to check for error, and test is using [Jasmine Async API](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

```
it('should throw an error', function (done) {
// ----- use Jasmine async API -------^^^

    var instance = instanceFactory.createInstance(someData);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(someFactory, 'someMethod').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    // here we continue catching and check the error
    var promise = instance.myFunc(otherData);
    promise.catch(function (err) {
        expect(err).toBe('Error in my function');
        done();
    });

    deferred.reject({data: '12 - error'});
    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

[Here is a working sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfzrKH8JXCO3zZlztSpN?p=preview) (open `script.js` file in sidebar)

Comment: #Michael Radionov I have a similar problem and your solution worked but I fear a false-positive:
`function A() {
  try {
    B()
  } catch (error) {
    $q.reject(error);
  }
  //everything is fine
  $q.resolve();

function B() { throw ({myError: {error: 'error_message')}}}`

The stranger thing is I've got the following error by applying your solution as-is:
`Expected { myError : { error : 'error_message' } } to be { myError: { error : 'error_message' } }`

But eventually, everything works when I move the `$rootScope.$digest` line **before** the `promise.catch etc` part

Comment: Regarding error message - `toBe` matcher compares objects by reference, you should use `toEqual` to perform deep equality comparison. That is because you are using errors as objects vs errors as strings in my example. I am not sure about the digest though, it would be great if you shared your updated code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Sorry for the convoluted previous comment and thank you in advance for your help, [here's the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2z4LmCSpCL8eTYvPErKH)

Comment: In the first example you call `$rootScope.$digest` before adding a catch handler, therefore the entire promise executes earlier than it gets to your catch - as a result test has **no** expectations and executes successfully. In the second example order is correct and error throws which is fine, but expectation fails because of the `toBe` vs `toEqual` difference I've explained above. Also, make sure to use Jasmine `done` for asynchronous test to spot false-positives, because it will explicitly wait for async expectations. [UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/XtwQZ3Empa2eA3unWmRu?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am unfamiliar with the done() practice because I'm using a 1.x jasmine version and I don't think I'm going to upgrade it right away: is there something I can do to mimic the done() mechanism?

Comment: You should check [Asynchronous support](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction?#section-Asynchronous_Support) section in Jasmine 1.x docs, it's a bit more complex than `done`, but gets the job done. The point is that you have a custom `flag`, which is false by default, and Jasmine `waitsFor` it to become true after some async operation, after it becomes true, Jasmine executes the last `runs` block with expectations.

Comment: #Michael Radionov, I think I'm still doing something wrong, but for StackOverflow sake I asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058499/is-this-jasmine-asynchronous-unit-test-result-a-false-positive), could you please take a look at it? Thank you in advance